# Rounding integers to nearest multiple of 10

Tags: c#, currency, rounding

I am trying to figure out how to round prices - both ways. For example:

```
Round down
43 becomes 40
143 becomes 140
1433 becomes 1430

Round up
43 becomes 50
143 becomes 150
1433 becomes 1440
```

I have the situation where I have a price range of say:

```
£143 - £193
```

of which I want to show as:

```
£140 - £200
```

as it looks a lot cleaner

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: I've tried Math.Floor

Comment: Floor is floor is for doubles.

Comment: divide by 10, round, multiply by 10

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I would just create a couple methods;

```
int RoundUp(int toRound)
{
     if (toRound % 10 == 0) return toRound;
     return (10 - toRound % 10) + toRound;
}

int RoundDown(int toRound)
{
    return toRound - toRound % 10;
}
```

Modulus gives us the remainder, in the case of rounding up `10 - r` takes you to the nearest tenth, to round down you just subtract r. Pretty straight forward.

Comment: The `RoundUp` is broken. If you pass `20`, it gets rounded up to `30` which is most likely not what you want. You can either do a conditional test (`if ((toRound % 10) == 0) return toRound;`) or use an unconditional rounding, for example `return ((toRound + 9) / 10) * 10;`

Comment: Note that the logic above only works for positive numbers (as I just found out).

Comment: Change to `Math.Abs(toRound) % 10` if you have negatives anywhere in price calc or otherwise.

Comment: As stated in the first comment on your answer, `RoundUp(20)` returns `30`.

Answer (score 16):

You don't need to use modulus (%) or floating point...

This works:

```
public static int RoundUp(int value)
{
    return 10*((value + 9)/10);
}

public static int RoundDown(int value)
{
    return 10*(value/10);
}
```

Comment: Might not give you what you want for very large numbers (e.g. Int32.MaxValue)

Comment: Yes, RoundUp will fail for numbers higher than (int32.MaxValue-10). Don't think that's an issue for prices in pounds though. And it's not possible to round those numbers up anyway, by any means (unless you return a long).

Comment: This worked well for me, and I like that it does not use modulus. Equivalent in Go:

    func RoundUp(v int) int {
     return 10 * ((v + 9) / 10)
    }

    func RoundDown(v int) int {
     return 10 * (v / 10)
    }

Comment: This RoundDown implementation doesn't work for negative value.

Comment: @NicFoster It's not required to work for negative numbers - it's for rounding prices.

Answer (score 13):

This code rounds to the nearest multiple of 10:

```
int RoundNum(int num)
{
     int rem = num % 10;
     return rem >= 5 ? (num - rem + 10) : (num - rem);
}
```

Very simple usage :

```
Console.WriteLine(RoundNum(143)); // prints 140
Console.WriteLine(RoundNum(193)); // prints 190
```

Comment: Gives the wrong answer for 1433 according to the spec.

Answer (score 5):

A general method to round a number to a multiple of another number, rounding [away from zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_away_from_zero).

**For integer**

```
int RoundNum(int num, int step)
{
    if (num >= 0)
        return ((num + (step / 2)) / step) * step;
    else
        return ((num - (step / 2)) / step) * step;
}
```

**For float**

```
float RoundNum(float num, float step)
{
    if (num >= 0)
        return floor((num + step / 2) / step) * step;
    else
        return ceil((num - step / 2) / step) * step;
}
```

I know some parts might seem counter-intuitive or not very optimized. I tried casting (num + step / 2) to an int, but this gave wrong results for negative floats (`(int) -12.0000 = -11` and such). Anyways these are a few cases I tested:

- any number rounded to step 1 should be itself
- -3 rounded to step 2 = -4
- -2 rounded to step 2 = -2
- 3 rounded to step 2 = 4
- 2 rounded to step 2 = 2
- -2.3 rounded to step 0.2 = -2.4
- -2.4 rounded to step 0.2 = -2.4
- 2.3 rounded to step 0.2 = 2.4
- 2.4 rounded to step 0.2 = 2.4

Answer (score 4):

Divide the number by 10.

```
number = number / 10;
Math.Ceiling(number);//round up
Math.Round(number);//round down
```

Then multiply by 10.

```
number = number * 10;
```

Comment: Gives the wrong answer for 1433 according to the spec

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int Round(int n)
        {
            // Smaller multiple 
            int a = (n / 10) * 10;

            // Larger multiple 
            int b = a + 10;

            // Return of closest of two 
            return (n - a > b - n) ? b : a;
        }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Doesn't work with negative numbers.