# ROUNDUP(700.25;-1) returns 710, how to we do this in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am building an Application based on a excel sheet, at a certain point the sheet uses 
=ROUNDUP(701.25;-1) which is returned as 710... how do we do this in C#

I tried Math.Round that returns 701, If I try to use Math.Round() with -1 then i get this

Rounding digits must be between 0 and 15, inclusive.

Please help me out here.

Comment: can you explain what is your need clearly

Comment: @Thamotharan He wants to implement this in C#: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/roundup-HP005209242.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try this (you'll need to cast the return value to `int` if necessary):

```
public static double RoundUp(double value, int digits)
{
    double pow = Math.Pow(10, digits);
    return Math.Ceiling(value * pow) / pow;
}
```

This should give you the functionality defined here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/roundup-HP005209242.aspx

Comment: `decimal calvalue = 701.25;
 calvalue = calvalue / 10;
 calvalue = Math.Ceiling(calvalue) * 10;`

I am using this much less complicated, what do  you think @matthew and  @Thamotharan

Answer (score 1):

use the below two methods.Which may help you

```
int RoundUp(int toRound)
{
     return (10 - toRound % 10) + toRound;
}

int RoundDown(int toRound)
{
    return toRound - toRound % 10;
}
```

Referenece
[Rounding integers to nearest multiple of 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154457/rounding-integers-to-nearest-multiple-of-10)