# Substring to position + exact char

Tags: c++, string, substring

I need to get a part of a string but 'round' the cut to the next exact char ',' to avoid bad cut ; 
Much more clear with this example :

```
string hand =  "AA,KK,QQ,JJ,AKs,AKo,AQs,AQo,TT,AJs,ATs,AJo,KQs,KJs,KTs,QJs,ATo,QTs,JTs,A9s,A9o,KQo,A8s,A8o,A7s,A7o,A6s,A6o,A5s,A5o,A4s,99,A4o,A3s,A2s,KJo,J9s,T9s,Q9s,QJo,KTo,Q9o,88,77,66,QTo,A3o,A2o,JTo,K9s,K8s,K7s,K6s,K5s,K4s,K3s,K2s,Q8s,Q7s,Q6s,Q5s,K9o,J8s,T8s,98s,97s,87s,86s,76s,96s,75s,65s,64s,J9o,T9o,55,54s,53s,52s,K8o,43s,32s,42s,J7s,T7s,K7o,44,33,22,Q4s,Q3s,Q2s,J6s,J5s,T6s,T5s,J4s,K6o,Q8o,J8o,T8o,98o,97o,87o,85s,K5o,K4o,K3o,K2o,95s,74s,76o,65o,54o,84s,94s,Q7o,J7o,T7o,Q6o,J3s,T4s,J2s,Q5o,T3s,T2s,Q4o,J6o,86o,T6o,96o,93s,Q3o,74o,84o,75o,64o,T2o,94o,53o,93o,63o,43o,92o,73o,83o,52o,82o,42o,62o,72o,J5o,63s,92s,73s,Q2o,J4o,83s,85o,82s,T5o,95o,J3o,62s,T4o,J2o,72s,T3o,32o";
```

The hand lenght is 662 .I want to get lets say the first 7% of the string hand :

```
  int startpos = 0;
  int stoppos= (662 * 7) / 100;
  string str2 = hand.substr(startpos, stoppos);
  cout <<  str2 << endl;
```

this will output **KTs,QJs,A**

As you see the final hand was cut , so i 'd like to substring to the next coma to have this outputt : **KTs,QJs,ATo,**

i'm a c++ beginer .

Comment: You've picked the wrong language for string wrangling. If you must, have a look at boost split: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#idp424404576

Answer (score 0):

since each hand takes up 4 characters (including the last comma), you might just round your stoppos to the nearest multiple of 4:

```
int stoppos = (169 * 7) / 100;
stoppos = stoppos - stoppos % 4; // round down to nearest multiple of 4
stoppos = (4 - stoppos % 4) + stoppos; // round up to nearest multiple of 4
```

This will output **KTs,QJs,** or **KTs,QJs,ATo,**, depending whether you choose to round up or down. If you don't want to keep the last comma, you might do an additional `- 1`:

```
stoppos = stoppos - stoppos % 4 - 1;
```

for more ideas on how to round to the nearest multiple of 4, you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15154457/2082964)

Comment: your example outputing KTs, QJ

Comment: I made a mistake in the offset, I fixed it now.

Comment: in that case we should round up instead of round down. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: I was off by one. I adapted it and tested it, it should be ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3407254/2425366

```
int roundUp(int numToRound, int multiple) { 
    if(multiple == 0) return numToRound;
    int remainder = numToRound % multiple;
    if (remainder == 0) return numToRound;
    return numToRound + multiple - remainder;
}
```

as `stoppos = roundUp(stoppos, 4)`;

Comment: thanks works nicely , but if i try to startpos = 99 and stopos=100 , it doesn't work , shoudl i need a roundDown function for this case ?

Comment: @guillaumeimportexport Comment out the third line.

Comment: strangly this seems no more work when my string lenght is 662 .. i edited my post with the string 662 length , test it with 98% to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how it can be done.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct classInstance {};

int main() 
{
    std::string hand = "KTs,QJs,ATo,QTs,JTs,A9s,A9o,KQo,A8s,A8o,A7s,A7o,A6s,A6o,A5s,A5o,A4s,"
                       "99,A4o,A3s,A2s,KJo,J9s,T9s,Q9s,QJo,KTo,Q9o,88,77,66,QTo,A3o,A2o,JTo";

    std::string::size_type start_pos;
    std::string::size_type char_num;

    start_pos = 0;
    char_num = 7 * hand.size() / 100;

    if ( start_pos + char_num < hand.size() )
    {        
        char_num = hand.find( ',', start_pos + char_num );
        if ( char_num != std::string::npos ) char_num -= start_pos - 1; 
    }

    std::string s = hand.substr( start_pos, char_num );

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
KTs,QJs,ATo,
```

Take into account that the second parameter of the member function `substr` specifies the number of characters to extract.