# Rounding pos and neg numbers to the nearest 10

Tags: c#, math, converters, rounding

I am having some trouble with a rounding issue. I have a converter to update a graphs scale to the nearest 10, based on what value comes in. the value can be either positive or negative.

I have attempted to build a math statement to round to the nearest 10 however with exceptionally small numbers it doesn't work. (numbers under 5).

the value that comes in is a double, but will be displayed in an int. any help with seeing what I did wrong would be great.

```
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
                return (int)((double)value >= 0 ? 
                        (Math.Round((double)value / 10, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 10) : 
                        (Math.Abs((Math.Round((double)value / 10, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 10)) * -1));
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding integers to nearest multiple of 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154457/rounding-integers-to-nearest-multiple-of-10)

Comment: What would you expect a number of 3 to be rounded to? I´d think of zero, you not? `Round(3 / 10) = 0`. So also multiplying 10 won´t change this.

Comment: So, you want values > 0 and < 10 to round to 10?  What about 0?  If that's what you want just add an `if` to check that.  rounding isn't going to do what you want.

Comment: And what about 11? Should it be rounded to 10 or 20?

Comment: anything under 0->9 needs to round to 10, 0 -> -9 needs to round to -10, Not being too familiar with the midpointrounding, using documentation it should round away from 0 regardless of what value it is however it seems to not work as I understand it

Comment: @HimBromBeere 11 should be 20

Comment: @asuppa The midpoint rounding is only to determine what to do with the midpoint (5).  Otherwise it rounds 1-4 down and 6-9 up.  It sounds like what you want is to truncate and if there is a remainder add one (or subtract).

Comment: Then itr is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921180/how-can-i-ensure-that-a-division-of-integers-is-always-rounded-up/926806

Comment: How should zero be once up to 10, but also down to -10? So what exactly to do with multiples of 10? Leave them or round to next 10?

Comment: What should 0.1 and -0.1 round to? You really need to be specific about ranges here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
return value > 0 ? 
    Math.Ceiling(value / 10) * 10 : 
    Math.Ceiling(Math.Abs(value) / 10) * -10;
```

Comment: this is the answer the ceiling operator is what I needed. Can't believe I missed that.