# Round Integral numbers in C#

Tags: c#, .net, numbers, int, rounding

I've been searching about this question for a few hours but I didn't find my answer so I ask it:

I'm looking for a method or something to round `25,599,999` to `25,000,000` or `25,599,999` to `30,000,000`:

```
 int num1 = 25599999;
 Console.WriteLine(RoundDown(num1, 6 /* This is the places (numbers from end that must be 0) */)) // Should return 25,000,000;
```

or Round Up:

```
 int num1 = 25599999;
 Console.WriteLine(RoundUp(num1, 6 /* This is the places (numbers from end that must be 0) */)) // Should return 30,000,000;
```

**Note:** I'm not looking for a way to round decimal numbers.

Comment: Search for "round to nearest multiple" there's plenty of answers

Comment: What did you try? Show your code. I don't think you can find this kind of customization directly.

Comment: `Math.Floor`, `Math.Ceiling`?

Comment: I'm not looking for rounding decimal numbers. @Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: Don't vote down, read the question and keep in mind that I'm not stupid to ask questions that has been answered many times.

Comment: Just to be clear, if you had `20,000,001` and you wanted to round UP using `8` significant digits, you'd want the result to be `30,000,000`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding integers to nearest multiple of 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154457/rounding-integers-to-nearest-multiple-of-10)

Comment: @Matthew Watson Yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int RoundDown(int num, int digitsToRound)
{
    double tmp = num / Math.Pow(10, digitsToRound);

    return (int)(Math.Floor(tmp) * Math.Pow(10, digitsToRound));
}

int RoundUp(int num, int digitsToRound)
{
    double tmp = num / Math.Pow(10, (digitsToRound + 1)) + 1;

    return (int)(Math.Floor(tmp) * Math.Pow(10, (digitsToRound + 1)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Methods for Rounding up and down for expected trailing zero count:

```
    public static int RoundUp(int number, int trailingZeroes)
    {
        var divider = (int)Math.Pow(10, trailingZeroes);
        return (number / divider + (number % divider > 0 ? 1 : 0)) * divider;
    }

    public static int RoundDown(int number, int trailingZeroes)
    {
        var divider = (int)Math.Pow(10, trailingZeroes);
        return number / divider * divider;
    }
```

This would however return for:

```
Console.WriteLine(RoundUp(25599999, 6));
```

Result will be 26 000 000. If you want it to be rounded to 30 000 000 then you need to call it with 7 trailing zeroes since in your example you are rounding to 7 trailing zeroes:

```
Console.WriteLine(RoundUp(25599999, 7));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

```
Math.Round
```

Example usage: [Rounding a Floating-Point Value](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-cookbook/0596003390/ch01s09.html)

Might be transferable to non-floating point values.
Maybe that helps you?

Answer (score -1):

You can try these functions:

```
public void RoundUp(int n){
    int up = ((n / 1000000) + 1) * 1000000;
    return up;
}

public void RoundDown(int n){
    int down = (n / 1000000) * 1000000;
    return down;
}
```

This only works with millions number (like 2 000 000, 25 252 325, ...).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yep sorry, i'm used to another language. I'm changing that